# How can I use LESS to personalize Ant Design Vue with nuxt?

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, less-loader

I try to use Ant Design Vue with NUXT.
I install nuxt with the commande line npm init nuxt-app 
And I choose Ant Design Vue.
It works perfectly.

But when I try to personnalize the theme (https://www.antdv.com/docs/vue/customize-theme/), it does not work.

I add less with npm but when I want to add less-loader I have this error message :

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.26.2 npm ERR!
> node_modules/webpack npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from
> babel-loader@8.2.2 npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader npm ERR!
> babel-loader@"^8.2.2" from @nuxt/webpack@2.15.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@nuxt/webpack npm ERR!       @nuxt/webpack@"2.15.3" from
> @nuxt/builder@2.15.3 npm ERR!       node_modules/@nuxt/builder npm
> ERR!         @nuxt/builder@"2.15.3" from nuxt@2.15.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/nuxt npm ERR!       1 more (nuxt) npm ERR!   peer
> webpack@"^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0" from css-loader@4.3.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/css-loader npm ERR!     css-loader@"^4.3.0" from
> @nuxt/webpack@2.15.3 npm ERR!     node_modules/@nuxt/webpack npm ERR!
> @nuxt/webpack@"2.15.3" from @nuxt/builder@2.15.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@nuxt/builder npm ERR!         @nuxt/builder@"2.15.3"
> from nuxt@2.15.3 npm ERR!         node_modules/nuxt npm ERR!       1
> more (nuxt) npm ERR!     peer css-loader@"*" from vue-loader@15.9.6
> npm ERR!     node_modules/vue-loader npm ERR!
> vue-loader@"^15.9.6" from @nuxt/webpack@2.15.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@nuxt/webpack npm ERR!         @nuxt/webpack@"2.15.3"
> from @nuxt/builder@2.15.3 npm ERR!         node_modules/@nuxt/builder
> npm ERR!         1 more (nuxt) npm ERR!   12 more
> (extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin, file-loader, ...) npm ERR!  npm
> ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer webpack@"^2.0.0 ||
> ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@2.5.0 npm
> ERR! node_modules/@nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin npm ERR!
> @nuxt/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^2.5.0" from
> @nuxt/webpack@2.15.3 npm ERR!   node_modules/@nuxt/webpack npm ERR!
> @nuxt/webpack@"2.15.3" from @nuxt/builder@2.15.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@nuxt/builder npm ERR!       @nuxt/builder@"2.15.3" from
> nuxt@2.15.3 npm ERR!       node_modules/nuxt npm ERR!     1 more
> (nuxt) npm ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or
> retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm
> ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
> resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR! See
> /Users/chtouk/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/chtouk/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T09_53_47_196Z-debug.log

So I tried to fix this with --force or --legacy-peer-deps but when I run my app with npm run dev, there is a new error message :

> ERROR  Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and
> test + include + exclude) in {
> 10:59:59   "use": [
> {
> "loader": "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
> "options": {
> "configFile": false,
> "babelrc": false,
> "cacheDirectory": true,
> "envName": "client",
> "presets": [
> [
> "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js",
> {
> "corejs": {
> "version": 3
> }
> }
> ]
> ]
> },
> "ident": "clonedRuleSet-4[0].rules[0].use[0]"
> }   ] }
>
> "use": [   {   "loader": "node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
> "options": {   "configFile": false,   "babelrc": false,
> "cacheDirectory": true,   "envName": "client",   "presets": [   [
> "node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js",   {   "corejs": {
> "version": 3   }   }   ]   ]   },   "ident":
> "clonedRuleSet-4[0].rules[0].use[0]"   }   ]   }

How can I fix it and personalize my theme ?

Thanks a lot for helping